# Getting an error in multi ./src/styles.scss when I try to deploy my angular app to heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, ecmascript-6, sass, single-page-application

When I try to deploy my angular app to heroku I'm getting a weird error.

I've tried switching the styles path in angular.json, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I'm pretty sure it's a path issue, but I cannot seem to fix it.

This is showing that I've switched it from "sass to scss"

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {"style": "scss"}
```

This is my current path

```
"styles": ["src/styles/global/global-styles.scss"]
```

This is my global-styles.scss

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

I want this to build to heroku, but instead its rejected and giving me this error:

```
remote: ERROR in multi ./src/styles.scss ../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
remote: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/tmp/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' in '/tmp/build_e2cd2f4e9e4c7e4749537f06bef83c35'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what was happening is that angular seemed to be caching something, I had to delete font awesome from node_modules and from the package.json, and move my files to a different folder in order to fix this issue. I'm sure there is a better way around this, but that is what I did in order to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem come from these line

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Your prod source code cant find node_modules folder contain these 2 package. So I would suggest you include css in your angular.json something like this

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
],
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, I got the same error.